# Return even empty groups when grouping by date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
           COUNT(CD_BarCode)
           ,CD_Carrier
           ,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR,DT_Arriving,103),1,11) Date
FROM TB_AGIL 
WHERE 
           DT_Arriving >= @date
           AND DT_Arriving < DATEADD(MONTH,+1,@date)
           AND CD_TRACKING = 14
GROUP BY CD_Carrier, SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR,DT_Arriving,103),1,11)
ORDER BY Date
```

I use this to see the results from last month's cargo movimentation. The results are a list of *cd_tracking* amount grouped by date like this:

```
| Amount | Carrier |    Date    |
|--------|---------|------------|
|  2599  |   44    | 01/08/2015 |
|  2504  |   44    | 03/08/2015 |
|  4597  |   44    | 04/08/2015 |
|  5058  |   44    | 05/08/2015 |
|  2413  |   44    | 06/08/2015 |
|  4853  |   44    | 07/08/2015 |
```

My problem is that if there is no *cd_tracking = 14* on a given day, that day will not show on the result list. As you can see, there is no *Aug 2nd* on the list.

I'd like to know if there is a way to bring every day on the result list, even if there is no *cd_tracking = 14* on that day. Like this:

```
| Amount | Carrier |    Date    |
|--------|---------|------------|
|  2599  |   44    | 01/08/2015 |
|  NULL  |   44    | 02/08/2015 |
|  2504  |   44    | 03/08/2015 |
|  4597  |   44    | 04/08/2015 |
|  5058  |   44    | 05/08/2015 |
|  2413  |   44    | 06/08/2015 |
|  4853  |   44    | 07/08/2015 |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the condition from the `WHERE` clause to a conditional count:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN CD_TRACKING = 14 THEN CD_BarCode ELSE NULL END),
    CD_Carrier,
    DATEPART(DAY, DT_Arriving) as [Date]
FROM TB_AGIL 
WHERE
    DT_Arriving >= @date
    AND DT_Arriving < DATEADD(MONTH,+1,@date)
GROUP BY 
    CD_Carrier, 
    DATEPART(DAY, DT_Arriving)
ORDER BY 
    [Date];
```

Other approaches to implement the [deprecated](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729(v=sql.100).aspx) `GROUP BY ALL` [syntax](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175028(v=sql.90).aspx) can be found [here](http://beyondrelational.com/quiz/sqlserver/tsql/2011/questions/write-a-replacement-for-group-by-all.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

For these kind of reports I prefer to use a [table of numbers](http://web.archive.org/web/20150411042510/http://web.archive.org/web/20150411042510/http://web.archive.org/web/20150411042510/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-numbers-table.html) or [calendar table](http://web.archive.org/web/20150512230546/http://web.archive.org/web/20070611150639/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html). Table of numbers is simply a table that has one column with integer numbers from 1 to some large enough number, say, 100,000. I personally use table with 100K numbers. Aaron Bertrand wrote a [good article](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1) explaining how to generate such table. Calendar table is simply a table that has one column with dates covering large enough range. Usually all dates from 1900 to 2200 would be enough.

So, once you have a table `Calendar` with column `dt`, which has `date` values and is a primary key, we can use it in your query.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Calendar](
    [dt] [date] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Calendar] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [dt] ASC
))
```

`DISTINCT` doesn't do anything in your `SELECT`, so I removed it. To group by `date` I cast the `DT_Arriving` to `date` type, rather than `varchar`. I assume `DT_Arriving` is not of `date` type. If it is, then cast is not needed. If you really need to return dates to the client as `varchar`, do it in the final `SELECT`.

`CTE_Main` is your original query. We need full month of dates for each `CD_Carrier` that appears in the result of `CTE_Main`. So, `CTE_Carriers` gives us a list of all `CD_Carrier` values. We `CROSS JOIN` it with the `Calendar` table to get a list of all dates of the month for each `CD_Carrier`. Then we `LEFT JOIN` `CTE_Main` to this result to get `Amount`.

```
WITH
CTE_Main
AS
(
    SELECT
        COUNT(CD_BarCode) AS Amount
        ,CD_Carrier
        ,CAST(DT_Arriving AS date) AS dt
    FROM TB_AGIL 
    WHERE 
        DT_Arriving >= @date
        AND DT_Arriving < DATEADD(MONTH,+1,@date)
        AND CD_TRACKING = 14
    GROUP BY CD_Carrier, CAST(DT_Arriving AS date)
)
,CTE_Carriers
AS
(
    SELECT CD_Carrier
    FROM CTE_Main
    GROUP BY CD_Carrier
)
SELECT
    CTE_Main.Amount
    ,CTE_Carriers.CD_Carrier
    ,Calendar.dt
FROM
    CTE_Carriers
    CROSS JOIN Calendar
    LEFT JOIN CTE_Main ON 
        CTE_Main.CD_Carrier = CTE_Carriers.CD_Carrier
        AND CTE_Main.dt = Calendar.dt
WHERE
    Calendar.dt >= @date
    AND Calendar.dt < DATEADD(MONTH,+1,@date)
ORDER BY dt;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the dates aren't in your resultset then you need to get them from somewhere right?  You could create a join with a derived table full of dates.